# scala parallel collections not consistent

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I am getting inconsistent answers from the following code which I find odd.

```
import scala.math.pow

val p = 2
val a = Array(1,2,3)

println(a.par
    .aggregate("0")((x, y) => s"$y pow $p; ", (x, y) => x + y))

for (i <- 1 to 100) {
  println(a.par
    .aggregate(0.0)((x, y) => pow(y, p), (x, y) => x + y) == 14)
}

a.map(x => pow(x,p)).sum
```

In the code the `a.par ...` computes `14` **or** `10`. Can anyone provide an explanation for why it is computing inconsistently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your "seqop" function, that is the first function you pass to `aggregate`, you define the logic that is used to combine elements within the *same* partition. Your function looks like this:

```
(x, y) => pow(y, p)
```

The problem is that you don't accumulate the results of a partition. Instead, you throw away your accumulator `x`. Every time you get 10 as a result, the calculation `2^2` was dropped.

If you change your function to take the accumulated value into account, you will get 14 every time:

```
(x, y) => x + pow(y, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use aggregate is

```
    a.par.aggregate(0.0)(
        (acc, value) => acc + pow(value, 2), (acc1, acc2) => acc1 + acc2
    )
```

By using (x,y) => pow(y,2) , you did not accumulate the item to the accumulator but just replaced the accumulator by pow(y,2).